# Can twitter do callbacks?

Tags: java, api, twitter, callback

I am wondering if the twitter API supports the following:

Whenever I make a post to my twitter account - it also calls a specific URL which I define so I can do something else?

Thanks very much,

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look Twitter supports this in their current API, however it wouldn't be difficult to create using a service which follows an RSS feed. In this case, you'd just have to wait for the RSS feed to update, and call whatever function you require.

E.g. http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/24671335.rss

If you can't run the service yourself, you could just create a web service and host it on AppEngine or Heroku — depending on your language preference of Python or Ruby, respectively.

Comment: I would be using Java - is there a decent library or something which I can use to retrive an RSS feed and find the updates since last check?

Comment: You can of course also use Java on App Engine. There seems to be RSS libraries for Java, I have no deeper knowledge about them, but Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you follow your account from another account and monitor that one to trigger whatever needs triggering?

I feel that twitter is becoming more and more one giant worldwide callback mechanism.

Comment: what benefit would that offer other than just monitoring the RSS feed of the original account? I dont know much about twitter you see!